# Show that $AB = 3AD$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

[image]

Given that $AF=EF$ and $BE=CE$. Show that $AB=3AD$.

This question was given during my exams today and it surprised my whole class. No one knew how to start and any tips would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be a midpoint of $BD$.

Thus, $GE||DC$ and since $F$ is a midpoint of $AE$, we obtain $AF=FG=GB$ and we are done!

Comment: Why would $GE$ be parallel to $DC$ ?

Comment: @Arc Neoepi Because $BE=EC$ and $BG=GD$. Just $GE$ is a midline of $\Delta BDC$.

Comment: Wait, it is a theorem? Because I don't remember hearing it in class before

Comment: @Arc Neoepi It's a theorem about a midline of the triangle.

Comment: @ArcNeoepi  $\Delta CBD$ and $\Delta EBG$ are similar by side-angle-side.  So $\angle BGE$ and $\angle BDC$ are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Use Menelaus's Theorem for $\Delta ABE$ and line $CFD$:

$$\frac{CB}{CE}\cdot\frac{FE}{FA}\cdot\frac{DA}{DB}=1$$

but $AF=EF$ and $BE=CE$, so,

$$2\cdot1\cdot\frac{DA}{DB}=1\to DB=2DA \to AB=3AD$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a point on $BD$ such that $EX\parallel CD$. Then $$\frac{BX}{XD}=\frac{BE}{EC}=1$$ and $$\frac{AD}{DX}=\frac{AF}{FE}=1.$$ It follows that $AD=DX=XB$, so $AB=3AD$.

Comment: How did you know we must let $X$ be a point on $BD$ such that $EX$ is parallel to $CD$

Comment: @ArcNeoepi Parallel lines allow to write equalities regarding ratios so I thought it'd be a good idea and indeed it led to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Draw $F'$ symmetric of $F$ wrt $E$

$BFCF'$ is a parallelogram and for Thales' theorem as $FF'=2AF$ also $BD=2AD$

*QED*

[image]